# How to know that when vm.runInContext finishes it's execution

Tags: node.js

This is my code

```
var offer = {title:'fdsfds',price:323,value:140};
    var initSandbox = {
            http: http,
            offer: offer
        };
var context = vm.createContext(initSandbox);
vm.runInContext(code, context);
```

when runIncontext successfully execute code in provided context it updates offer object in context so i need to know when it completes it's execution so i can retrive offer object from context.

Comment: Use clear language and code formatting! It's very hard to follow your question now.

Answer (score 6):

Pass callback to your context and trigger it from your code

```
var vm = require('vm');
var offer = {title:'fdsfds',price:323,value:140};
var initSandbox = {
    http: 123,
    offer: offer,
    done : function(offer) {
        console.log('done!');
    },
    setTimeout: setTimeout
};
var context = vm.createContext(initSandbox);
vm.runInContext("setTimeout(done,100)", context);
```